# Internal Server Error -> RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm getting Internal Server Error with this .htaccess file:

```
Allow from all

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Important: RewriteBase
    # If you installed the web app in a sub-directory you have to set this accordingly.
    # Note: No trailing slash! (f.e. /BoNeMEAL or /mc-server/ban-management)
    RewriteBase /home/webpages/lima-city/townville/bans

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: That means you have a syntax error in the htaccess file. What error do you get in apache's `error.log`?

Answer (score 1):

RewriteBase must contain path from server root (dir pointed by www.example.com) to dir where .htaccess placed (in this case). So if your server root at /home/webpages/lima-city/townville/bans then say

```
RewriteBase /
```